# Update Only Part of ContentView Display

Tags: swiftui

Hobbyist here and I'm working on an app for my own use. ContentView will have some buttons and sliders and most importantly, two rectangle views; one shows a random colour and the other shows a colour that the user can set via 3 sliders (hue, saturation, brightness). I originally had all code in the ContentView but every time I moved a slider the rectangle that shows the random colour updated with a new colour. The sliders did control the 2nd rectangle but the entire view was redrawn and a new random colour was shown (not what I wanted). I created a 2nd view file just to create the random colour rectangle and figured I'd call the 2nd view from a button. Now, the 2nd view is only updated when I initially start the app. I want the Random Colour button to only update the random colour view and not the rectangle controlled by the sliders. Now I get an xcode warning saying "Result of FandomColourView initializer is unused".
I've searched Stack OverFlow and many other web sites trying to figure this out and can't find the answer. I must say that I am having a real hard time internalizing the swiftui paradigm vs. UIKit.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var hue: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
@State var sat: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
@State var bri: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)

var body: some View {
    let colour2 = Color.init(hue: hue, saturation: sat, brightness: bri)
    VStack {    // main vstack
        TitleColoursView()
        RandomColourView()
        Text("Sliders Colour")
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(colour2)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
            .border(.black, width: 5)
            .padding()
        HStack (spacing: 200) {
            Button("Red") {
                hue = 0.0
                sat = 1.0
                bri = 1.0
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Button("Green") {
                hue = 0.33333
                sat = 1.0
                bri = 1.0
            }
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            Button("Blue") {
                hue = 0.66666
                sat = 1.0
                bri = 1.0
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 28))
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
        Group{
            DrawslidersView(value: $hue, title: "Hue")
            DrawslidersView(value: $sat, title: "Saturation")
            DrawslidersView(value: $bri, title: "Brightness")
            Button("Reset"){
                hue = 0.5
                sat = 0.5
                bri = 0.5
            }
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            Button("New Random") {
                
                RandomColourView()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my view for the sliders.

```
struct DrawslidersView: View {
@Binding var value: Double
var title: String

var body: some View {
    Text(title + " value = " + String(format: "%.4f", value))
        .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
    HStack {
        Text("0")
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            .padding(.leading, 25)
            .padding(.trailing, 5)
        Slider(value: $value)
        Text("100")
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.trailing, 25)
    }
}
```

}
And finally, my 2nd view that creates the randomly selected colour rectangle.

```
struct RandomColourView: View {

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Text("Random Colour")
            .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.init(hue: Double.random(in: 0...1), saturation: Double.random(in: 0...1), brightness: Double.random(in: 0...1)))
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
                .border(.black, width: 5)
                .padding()
    }
}
```

}

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI you need to think in terms of `change of view states`. That is,
your code change a variable, and the View changes accordingly, rather
than present different views. Using `@State var` allows the View to take care
of refreshing itself automatically when the `@State var` is changed.

There are many ways to do what you want.
Here is some example code, that uses yet another construct, a `computed` property,
to "calculate/update" `colour2`. Also as an example, I added a `@State var newRandom` to
refresh your `RandomColourView` when you press the Button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var hue: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    @State var sat: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    @State var bri: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    
    @State var newRandom = true  // <-- here to trigger a refresh of RandomColourView
    
    // computed property
    var colour2: Color {
        Color(hue: hue, saturation: sat, brightness: bri)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {  // <-- here
            VStack {    // main vstack
                // TitleColoursView()
                RandomColourView(newRandom: newRandom)
                
                Text("Sliders Colour").font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 22))
                
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(colour2)
                    // alternatively without colour2
                    //.foregroundColor(Color(hue: hue, saturation: sat, brightness: bri))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
                    .border(.black, width: 5)
                    .padding()
                
                HStack (spacing: 10) {  // <-- here
                    Button("Red") {
                        hue = 0.0
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.red)
                    
                    Button("Green") {
                        hue = 0.33333
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.green)
                    
                    Button("Blue") {
                        hue = 0.66666
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 28))
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                
                Group{
                    DrawslidersView(value: $hue, title: "Hue")
                    DrawslidersView(value: $sat, title: "Saturation")
                    DrawslidersView(value: $bri, title: "Brightness")
                    
                    Button("Reset"){
                        hue = 0.5
                        sat = 0.5
                        bri = 0.5
                    }
                    .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    
                    Button("New Random") {
                        newRandom.toggle()  // <--- here, change the view state
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct RandomColourView: View {
    @State var newRandom: Bool  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random Colour")
                .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.init(hue: Double.random(in: 0...1), saturation: Double.random(in: 0...1), brightness: Double.random(in: 0...1)))
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
                .border(.black, width: 5)
                .padding()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Note, the xcode warning you get "Result of RandomColourView initializer is unused" is because
you have a `View` (RandomColourView) in a place in the Button,
that should not have a view, but some action code. Think in terms of `change of view states`.

EDIT-1:

Another approach is to make the `RandomColourView` tappable/clickable, to change the random color,
instead of adding another button. Such as in this example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hue: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    @State var sat: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)
    @State var bri: Double = Double.random(in: 0...1)

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {  // <-- here
            VStack {    // main vstack
                // TitleColoursView()
                
                // -- tap on the view to show another random color
                RandomColourView()
                
                Text("Sliders Colour").font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 28))
                
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hue: hue, saturation: sat, brightness: bri)) // <-- here
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
                    .border(.black, width: 5)
                    .padding()
                
                HStack (spacing: 10) {
                    Button("Red") {
                        hue = 0.0
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.red)
                    
                    Button("Green") {
                        hue = 0.33333
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.green)
                    
                    Button("Blue") {
                        hue = 0.66666
                        sat = 1.0
                        bri = 1.0
                    }.foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 28))
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                
                Group{
                    DrawslidersView(value: $hue, title: "Hue")
                    DrawslidersView(value: $sat, title: "Saturation")
                    DrawslidersView(value: $bri, title: "Brightness")
                    
                    Button("Reset"){
                        hue = 0.5
                        sat = 0.5
                        bri = 0.5
                    }
                    .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct RandomColourView: View {
    @State var refresh = false // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random Colour")
                .font(.custom("Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 26))
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(hue: Double.random(in: 0...1),
                                       saturation: Double.random(in: 0...1),
                                       brightness: Double.random(in: 0...1)))
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 250)
                .border(refresh ? .black : .black, width: 5) // <-- depends on refresh change
                .onTapGesture {
                    refresh.toggle() // <-- change some state
                }
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic - thank you! Love the idea of onTapGesture, I might need to add a text view over top of the rectangle saying "Tap To Change" or something like that to make it obvious that the tap will change the colour.

Comment: I noticed that in the solution you provided, you have a State var newRandom:Bool in both ContentView and RandomColourView. When I toggle the ContentView newRandom var via the button and then pass it to the RandomColourView, does that then update the RandomColourView newRandom var and because it is a State var, cause the view to be redrawn?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because `newRandom` is declared a `@State var` the View will keep an eye on it, 
and if that `State` changes,  the view will automatically refresh itself, **if** that view depends on that `@State var`. 
This is what SwiftUI View provides, as it implements a reactive/state base user interface. 
For your `RandomColourView`, you need to trick the view into updating itself, by changing 
`newRandom` to something, in your particualr case to anything, since the value is not used. Typically you 
would make use of the `new` value to update that particular value in your view.